# With Redux-Form V7, how to gain access to which fields are currently touched?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have a form (let's call it the **LoginContainer**) that has the `<Field />` component on it:

```
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form'
...
class LoginContainer extends Component {
...

render() {
  const { handleSubmit, pristine, submitting } = this.props

  return (
  ...

  <Field
    component={AuthFormInput}
    type="password"
    name="person_password"
    placeholder="Password"
  />
```

**AuthFormInput.jsx**

```
const AuthFormInput = ({
  input,
  name,
  placeholder,
  type,
  meta: { touched, error },
}) => {
  return [
    <div className="row-md" key={`${name}_field`}>
      <input
        placeholder={placeholder}
        name={name}
        type={type}
        className={maybeHasError}
        {...input}
      />
    </div>, // error display works amazing here, no problem
    <div key={`${name}_error`}>{touched && (error && <span className="edit_required">{error}</span>)}</div>,
  ]
}
```

The problem is, I am trying to handle errors outside of the `AuthFormInput` component, and I can't find any solution that allows me to access the `touched` state of each field from anywhere other than `AuthFormInput`, which is abstracted inside `<Field />`

Is there a way I can get access to `meta.touched` from inside `LoginContainer`?

Redux-Form doesn't seem to have any kind of `getTouchedFields()` function that I can use.

I can collect the currently errored fields easily through the validate function, but I can't find a way to see what fields are touched.

> I can't find a way to pass data from `AuthFormInput` to `LoginContainer` because `<Field />` is between them which is internally controlled by Redux-Form.

Is there any way to do this with Redux-Form V7?

Is there a way I can create a HOC that allows me to track `meta.touched` inside `<Field />`?

Comment: I just wrapped the field in a HOC and I am seeing shreds of evidence that this is going to work.

Comment: I'm not sure if that suitable for you, but I had similar issue, where I needed to access fields value (touched or not) on a form level. `getFormMeta` selector did it for me https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/selectors.md/

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I was able to achieve this and it was extremely non-trivial.

Stepping forward from the code in the above question, I added this to `LoginContainer`:

```
import withFormListener from './withFormListener'

const listeningAuthFormInput = withFormListener(AuthFormInput)
```

So, then `<Field />` became this:

```
<Field
  component={listeningAuthFormInput}
  type="password"
  name="person_password"
  placeholder="Password"
/>
```

The HOC wraps around the text input field (or any field you want), and simply listens for changes to the props and then updates Redux:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { updateField } from './auth_actions'

const withFormListener = function listenToFormField(FormField) {
  class WrappedField extends Component {
    handleFieldUpdate() {
      const { name } = this.props.input
      const { touched, error } = this.props.meta
      if (touched && error) {
        if (this.props[`error_${name}`] === error) return null
        return this.props.updateField({ prop: name, value: error })
      }
      if ((touched && !error) && this.props[`error_${name}`].length) {
        return this.props.updateField({ prop: name, value: '' })
      }
      return null
    }
    componentDidUpdate() {
      this.handleFieldUpdate()
    }
    render() {
      return <FormField {...this.props} />
    }
  }
  const mapStateToProps = ({
    auth: { error_person_tel, error_person_password },
  }) => ({
    error_person_tel, error_person_password,
  })
  return connect(mapStateToProps, { updateField })(WrappedField)
}

export default withFormListener
```

Logically, what is happening in the HOC is:

1. `this.props` inside `AuthFormInput` becomes `this.props` inside the HOC
2. listen to `this.props.meta` and `this.props.input`
3. if the field is touched and has an error, update Redux
4. if the field is touched and no longer has an error, wipe it out of Redux

You should see my action creator and reducer from `LoginContainer` so there is no confusion.

**Action Creator**

```
export const updateField = ({ prop, value }) => ({
  type: AUTH_UPDATE_FIELD,
  payload: { prop, value },
})
```

**Reducer**

I recommend keeping the state object **flat**. I experimented with nesting in here, such as:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  errors: { field1, field2 }
}
```

But, it was giving me significant problems with updating the state, due to equality reasons and complexity with avoiding overwriting `errors`. It's much nastier than it looks. Therefore, I have settled on this:

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  ...
  error_person_tel: '',
  error_person_password: '',
}

case AUTH_UPDATE_FIELD: {
  const { prop, value } = action.payload
  return {
    ...state,
    [`error_${prop}`]: value,
  }
}
```

You can read more about normalizing state here (ie: flattening):
https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

I haven't got around to optimizing it at all, but here is how I am displaying the errors currently (inside `LoginContainer`):

```
<ServerErrors
  errors={[
    this.props.error_person_tel,
    this.props.error_person_password,
  ].filter(val => val)}
/>
```

It is a simple component that renders either `null` or an array of error strings.

> I highly recommend using the built-in `Redux-Form` field error handling. It works great. I unfortunately had to abstract the control away from the field-level to accomplish a UI design, so this was the only solution in `V7`.

I searched for weeks. I made another Stack Overflow question and it got no activity, neither did this one. I'm glad I was able to achieve a functioning solution.

I also highly recommend you take a look at `Formik`. I used it in React Native to accomplish this UI requirement a few weeks ago. You will likely find it works very well. Talk to `Jared Palmer` on Twitter if you encounter any issues with it. Formik boasts performance gains vs. Redux-Form due to smarter architecture. I am very happy with it in React Native.

If you venture down this road, **be extremely careful about setting off infinite loops caused by `setState`**. I did hours and hours and hours of research and trial & error to make this :) I am reasonably happy with the conciseness of the solution. Please let me know if you have a better way.